# unable to delete s3 key with special characters in it

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-s3, command-line-interface, boto3, aws-cli

I have an s3 object with a special character in it \x{1B} (front of A)

```
aws --profile myprofile s3api delete-object --bucket test-bucket --key `ABCD` --version 1234
```

When I try using cli to delete it, due to special character it does not respect it.

If I try using boto3 with python via

```
bucket.object_versions.delete()
```

I get

```
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (MalformedXML) when calling the DeleteObjects operation: The XML you provided was not well-formed or did not validate against our published schema
```

If I try to delete from the UI, the operation is successful but the object doesn't disappear.

I'm looking to permanently delete that object.
Appreciate any pointers.

Comment: You say that when deleting via the S3 management console "the object doesn't disappear". Does the bucket have Versioning activated? If so, activate the **List versions** option and delete _all versions_ of the object. It will then disappear.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of back-quotes ` use single quotes '.

In the Linux/Unix shell, back quotes are meant to be used in order to run inline commands.

You can use `printf` to print anything by providing the hex code of that special character. For example, to add a tab into the key use:

```
--key `printf 'a\x09b'`
```

This time, back quotes are needed.

Comment: I tried both back quotes and single quotes. doesn't work. The minute the special character is encountered it triggers an ESC which clears out the console leaving me with half the statement a starting from A

Comment: @DJ_Stuffy_K In that case, please share with others the identity of your special character. And how did it get there? What method did you use to create a key with an unprintable character?

Comment: @DJ_Stuffy_K Added another suggestion to try and use `printf`

Comment: somebody created it and left it , I'm just trying to clean it up. The special character is `\x{1B}`

Comment: @DJ_Stuffy_K In that case replace `\x09` with `\x1b` in the example above

Comment: sadly i'm on a windows machine. let me see if powershell would allow that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227354/discussion-between-dj-stuffy-k-and-jonathan-jacobson).